# Large WCF proxy reference class slows down application startup

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, wcf-proxy

I try to speed up the startup time for running application with debugger. I noticed that it takes ~1.5min to create an object of a class, that's used as a proxy to WCF service. That class is inside reference.cs generated by using 'Add Service Reference' Visual Studio tool. Too bad it has 72732 lines of code with a couple of thousands of fields inside. I'm new to WCF and I'm wondering what would be the fastest way to improve performance here? what would be, maybe not that fastest, but the best approach to refactor this? any tips?

Comment: I would incline to use ChannelFactory rather than adding ServiceReference. Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory

Comment: In my opinion, using a client proxy to call the service is a good choice. You could also try the channel factory to call the service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/channel-factory